# How to get inner array values in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I want to create a new array from existing array.

```
someArray = [
  {
    "abc": "abc",
    "bbc": "bbc",
    "farcKeyValues": [
      {
        "caseCreator": "xyz",
        "caseOwner": "yyy",
        "symptomCode": "123"
      },
      {
        "caseCreator": "eyz",
        "caseOwner": "tyy",
        "symptomCode": "423"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "xyz": "xyz",
    "yyz": "yyz",
    "farcKeyValues": [
      {
        "caseCreator": "abc",
        "caseOwner": "aaa",
        "symptomCode": "234"
      },
      {
        "caseCreator": "ybc",
        "caseOwner": "dfa",
        "symptomCode": "834"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "zxc": "zxs",
    "rde": "rde",
    "farcKeyValues": [
      {
        "caseCreator": "wes",
        "caseOwner": "res",
        "symptomCode": "345"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Expected array to be created is

```
finalValue = [
  {
    "caseCreator": "xyz",
    "caseOwner": "yyy",
    "symptomCode": "123"
  },
  {
    "caseCreator": "eyz",
    "caseOwner": "tyy",
    "symptomCode": "423"
  },
  {
    "caseCreator": "abc",
    "caseOwner": "aaa",
    "symptomCode": "234"
  },
  {
    "caseCreator": "ybc",
    "caseOwner": "dfa",
    "symptomCode": "834"
  },
  {
    "caseCreator": "wes",
    "caseOwner": "res",
    "symptomCode": "345"
  }
];
```

I am able to read only the first item in the farcKeyValues like below

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.someArray.length; i++) {
  finalValue[i] = this.someArray[i].farcKeyValues[0];
}
```

Any help on how to read all the elements in the inner array and create new array with all the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var finalValue = [];

for (var i = 0; i < this.someArray.length; i++) {
  finalValue = [ ...finalValue, ...this.someArray[i].farcKeyValues ]
}
```

If you prefer a more functional approach:

```js
var finalValue = this.someArray.reduce((acc, item) => [...acc, ...item.farcKeyValues], [])
```

[You can read more about the spread operator here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)